# ProtocalError, Connection Broken: ConnectionResetError when pip installing tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, exception, pip

I have another question once again that is bugging me a ton.

**Context**

I am trying to install TensorFlow Object Detection API, and it's a pretty lengthy process. A part that I am getting stuck on is actually installing tensorflow. I created a python venv (virtual environment) and I configured my kernel on my jupyter notebook correctly so that all of the pip installations and packages stay within the directory indicated by my virtual environment. Now my pip install works on every package, but the following is an issue:

**Problem**

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.5.0
```

Which results in the following:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 462, in read
    n = self.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\http\client.py", line 506, in readinto
    n = self.fp.readinto(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\socket.py", line 704, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 338, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 482, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 349, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 201, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 281, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 292, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 527, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 213, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 94, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 145, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 144, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 541, in read
    raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 137, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Chang\Desktop\tf projects\tf Object Detection\TFOD\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 455, in _error_catcher
    raise ProtocolError("Connection broken: %r" % e, e)
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)", ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))
```

I am not expecting anyone to magically know what is going on because I understand that my PC is configured differently from the next person's. But just in case it matters, I am using a python venv, with python 3.9.7, my pip version is 21.3.1. I am particularly interested with the last few lines of this error.

**Question**

Although I would like a solution to this ideally, I also just want to know the potential source of this connection error? I turned off the proxy detection on my windows network settings, so I don't exactly know where the connection error is coming from? In the past, I always used anaconda and anaconda environments to use tensorflow, and I've never had an issue installing tensorflow from anaconda. I'm not sure why pip installing tensorflow in a non-anaconda, python venv gives me such an issue. I initially thought this was an issue with pip, but pip allowed me to install every other package I could think of just fine, it only has this particular error with tensorflow.

Any suggestions/help would be appreciated!

**EDIT 1 (2022-01-11)**

I didn't figure out what was the precise cause of my error, but my issue went away. What happened was that I configured my computer (anaconda and python specifically) in my current place of residence and on the WiFi at the place I live at. This error occurred when I traveled to a family member's home for the holiday season.

The discrepancy here is that tensorflow installation failed at my family's home, therefore, I hypothesize that the discrepancy in the IP addresses between where I live and my family's home likely raised a security flag in pip somewhere that cut the connection when I tried to install a package. This makes sense because installation through anaconda into a conda virtual environment worked properly, but only the pip install was giving me issues.

Answer (score 0):

PIP by default download and install packages from internet PYPI(Python Package Index) directly and install them in our Python environments. So you may need to be connected with internet to download those wheel packages(.whl).

Anaconda is a Python distribution and has prebuilt and preconfigured collection of packages.